# Android - change flavor version name based on build type

Tags: android, gradle

I want to change version name for app flavors but only if it's a debug build.

(e.g. debug builds will have versions like 1.0.1 D (DEBUG) 555 or 1.0.1 P (DEBUG) 555, however I want the release builds only to have version like 1.0.1)
How can I achieve this?

Basically I have these build types:

```
buildTypes {


    debug {
        versionNameSuffix " (DEBUG) " + mBuild

    }
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), file('proguard-project.txt')
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

and these flavors (for different api environment):

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + " D"
    }
    prod {
        versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + " P"
    }
}
```

Is there any way how to make release builds without product flavors version name change?

I've tried to set the version name dynamically via

```
    buildTypes.each { buildType ->
    if(buildType.name == 'debug') {
        productFlavors.dev.versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + " D"
    }
}
```

but this results in

> Could not find property 'dev' on GroupableProductFlavorDsl container.

Comment: Accept your own answer, please. So it's clear for community, that issue resolved.

Comment: "You can accept your own answer tomorrow"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After hours of searching I've managed to remove all the changes made to the version name for the release build using this code

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
        variant.mergedFlavor.versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName;
    }
}
```

Comment: this notation (android.defaultConfig.versionName) worked for me until today I upgraded from AndroidStudio 0.5.5 to 0.8.1. Any idea what should be used now instead?

Comment: I get a `Could not find property 'applicationVariants' on project:...` error.

Comment: use applicationVariants.each Instead of applicationVariants.all

Comment: To my surprise, this works for `android.libraryVrariants.all` as well.

Comment: This doesn't work, as this code creates a new variable "versionName" in `BuildConfig.java` rather than updating the existing versions in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I got the error: ```ERROR: versionCode cannot be set on a mergedFlavor directly.```

Answer (score 3):

For those wondering to use this using Kotlin DSL. At first try, it might not be allowing us to assign a new value to the version name.

[image]

The image above shown there's no setter for `versionName` for `ProductFlavor` class.

**Attempt 1 (cast to `ProductFlavorImpl`):**

```
applicationVariants.forEach { variant ->
  if (variant.buildType.name != "release") {
    variant.mergedFlavor.let {
      it as ProductFlavorImpl
      it.versionName = "sampingan-${defaultConfig.versionName}"
    }
  }
}
```

`it as ProductFlavorImpl` still doesn't work, due to `MergedFlavor` cannot be cast `ProductFlavorImpl` and throw this error:

```
com.android.builder.core.MergedFlavor cannot be cast to com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.dsl.model.ProductFlavorImpl
```

**Attempt 2 (casting to `MergedFlavor`) instead:**

```
  //
  variant.mergedFlavor.let {
    it as com.android.builder.core.MergedFlavor
  }
  //
```

After trial & error, it looks like we were unable to directly change the `versionName` with `MergedFlavor`, instead another error logs shown below:

```
versionName cannot be set on a mergedFlavor directly.
versionNameOverride can instead be set for variant outputs using the following syntax:
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.versionNameOverride = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

**Attempt 3 (using `ApplicationVariant` object) instead:**

So let's change our implementation to be like this

```
    applicationVariants.all(object : Action<com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant> {
        override fun execute(variant: com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant) {
            println("variant: ${variant}")
            variant.outputs.all(object : Action<com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariantOutput> {
                override fun execute(output: com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariantOutput) {

                    if (variant.buildType.name != "release") {
                    (output as com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApkVariantOutputImpl)
                            .versionNameOverride = "prefix-${variant.versionName}"
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

This whole approach, inspired by @david-mihola answer. He explained that `groovy` has its own magic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50801989/3763032).

And if you want to change the **APK name** for each different `buildTypes` or `productFlavors` you can go to @david-mihola answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50801989/3763032).

Answer (score 1):

The latest simple solution worked well and was tested. Define productflavour and buildTypes inside these and remove the versionName.

And using         `output.versionNameOverride = versionName` we can change versionName depending on buildType and productFlavour.

Code:

```
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def flavor = variant.getFlavorName()
        def versionName = "1.0.0"
        switch (flavor){
            case "paid":
                flavor = "Paid"
                if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
                    versionName = "1.0.0.8"
                } else if (variant.buildType.name == 'staging') {
                    versionName = "1.0.0.8"
                } else {
                    versionName = "1.0.0.8"
                }
                break
            case "free":
                flavor = "Free"
                if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
                    versionName = "1.0.0.14"
                } else if (variant.buildType.name == 'staging') {
                    versionName = "1.0.0.14"
                } else {
                    versionName = "1.0.0.14"
                }
                break
            case "trial":
                flavor = "Trial"
                if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
                    versionName = "1.0.0.3"
                } else if (variant.buildType.name == 'staging') {
                    versionName = "1.0.0.3"
                } else {
                    versionName = "1.0.0.3"
                }
                break
        }
        output.versionNameOverride = versionName
        outputFileName = "${flavor}_v${versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Build Type` should override the `Product Flavor`. Try next one.

```
buildTypes {

    release {
        versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that. The problem is that build type doesn't have versionName property, only versionNameSuffix. The code above results in 'Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been de
.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plu
on the replacement for dynamic properties.
Deprecated dynamic property: "versionName" on "BuildTypeDsl_Decorated'

Comment: Got the error: ```RROR: Could not set unknown property 'versionName' for BuildType_Decorated```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is using Gradle Kotlin DSL, you can write below code like this:

```
flavorDimensions.add("fruit")

productFlavors {
    create("apple") {
        dimension = "fruit"
    }
    create("tomato") {
        dimension = "fruit"
        versionName = "0.0.1-vegetable"
    }
}
```

Current Gradle version is 8.0.2

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to set a different **versionName** for **debug** build:

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            if (variant.buildType.name == 'debug') {
                output.versionNameOverride = "1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Marius make sure you have placed the code in the right place. We are using the exact same code in our production app without any issues.

Comment: I've tested it in different places and the version is not overriden. I've even tested it in a new project and looked at the `BuildConfig` file after building. Maybe you have to specify exactly where to put it in your answer.

Comment: Working solution