# Android - change app version name based on flavor

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I want to change the app `versionName` to whatever is defined in the AndroidManifest file for the specific flavor I'm building.

So if I'm only building one of the 4 defined flavors I have, like:
    gradle assembleFlavor1Debug

I was expecting `Flavor1` to have the same version name as the one defined for its specific manifest (because of the merging of manifest files), but that's not happening.

How can I know, during build time, which specific flavor is being built?
Because if I know what flavor is being run,
I can extract the respective `versionName` from the manifest and set it on `android.defaultConfig.versionName`,
which solves my problem.

Comment: Previous answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726119/android-change-flavor-version-name-based-on-build-type

Comment: @Turnsole the question you mentioned is very clear:'change flavor version name based on build type'. I don't want to change the versionName based on the 'build type', but rather on the specific flavor I'm building.

Comment: i had same issue. check this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737482/4908528)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of at least Android Studio 3.1.1 you can do this...

```
defaultConfig {
    versionName "1.0.0"
}
flavorDimensions "dimen1", "dimen2"
productFlavors {
    'flavor1' {
        dimension "dimen1"
        versionNameSuffix "-F1"
    }

    ...

    'flavorA' {
        dimension "dimen2"
        versionNameSuffix "-FA"
    }
}
```

Then for variant `flavor1FlavorA` the `versionName` would be `1.0.0-F1-FA`

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in this way

```
productFlavors
{
test
{
 applicationId 'com.example.test'
 versionName '1.0.0.test'
 versionCode 1
}

product
{
 applicationId 'com.example.product'
 versionName '1.0.0.product'
 versionCode 1
}
}
```