# How to access variant.outputFileName in Kotlin

Tags: gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

We've been using a snippet like this one to rename the APK file generated by our Gradle build:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration#variant_output

I am now in the process of converting my `build.gradle` to `build.gradle.kts`, i. e. to the Gradle Kotlin DSL. This is one of the last missing pieces: I can't figure out how to access `outputFileName`.

According to the API docs it does not even seem to exist:

- `BaseVariant.getOutputs()` returns a `DomainObjectCollection<BaseVariantOutput>` which provides the `all` method used in the snippet.
- `BaseVariantOutput` extends `OutputFile` which extends `VariantOutput` but none of these has an `outputFileName` or any getters or setters of a matching name.

So, I suspect there is some advanced Groovy magic at work to make this work - but how do I get there in Kotlin?

Comment: To the downvoter: Care to explain?

Comment: Any update for build.gradle.kts?

Answer (score 59):

A little simplified version of @david.mihola answer:

```kotlin
android {

    /**
    * Notes Impl: Use DomainObjectCollection#all
    */
    applicationVariants.all {
        val variant = this
        variant.outputs
            .map { it as com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.BaseVariantOutputImpl }
            .forEach { output ->
                val outputFileName = "YourAppName - ${variant.baseName} - ${variant.versionName} ${variant.versionCode}.apk"
                println("OutputFileName: $outputFileName")
                output.outputFileName = outputFileName
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please explain this synthax/sample and why do we still need to use BaseVariantOutputImpl ?

Comment: because we need to casting it, so we can access the setOuputFileName @Zingam cmiiw

Comment: @mochdawi  So is this due to some serious deficiency in Kotlin DSL?

Comment: From my experience, applicationVariants.forEach doesn't work (collection is empty), and you have to use applicationVariants.all{}. But not Kotlin's extension Iterable.all(), but DomainObjectCollection.all().

Comment: Instead of `.map{..}.forEach{..}` I'm using `.all { val output = this as BaseVariantOutputImpl; output.outputFileName = "..." }`

Answer (score 33):

Browsing through the source code of the Android Gradle plugin, I think I found the answer - here we go:

We are actually dealing with objects of type `BaseVariantOutputImpl` and this class *does* have both these methods:

```
public String getOutputFileName() {
    return apkData.getOutputFileName();
}

public void setOutputFileName(String outputFileName) {
    if (new File(outputFileName).isAbsolute()) {
        throw new GradleException("Absolute path are not supported when setting " +
                    "an output file name");
    }
    apkData.setOutputFileName(outputFileName);
}
```

Using this knowledge we can now:

```
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.BaseVariantOutputImpl
```

and then cast our target objects like so:

```
applicationVariants.all(object : Action<ApplicationVariant> {
    override fun execute(variant: ApplicationVariant) {
        println("variant: ${variant}")
        variant.outputs.all(object : Action<BaseVariantOutput> {
            override fun execute(output: BaseVariantOutput) {

                val outputImpl = output as BaseVariantOutputImpl
                val fileName = output.outputFileName
                        .replace("-release", "-release-v${defaultConfig.versionName}-vc${defaultConfig.versionCode}-$gitHash")
                        .replace("-debug", "-debug-v${defaultConfig.versionName}-vc${defaultConfig.versionCode}-$gitHash")
                println("output file name: ${fileName}")
                outputImpl.outputFileName = fileName
            }
        })
    }
})
```

So, I guess: Yes, there is some Groovy magic at work, namely that Groovy's dynamic type system allows you to just access `getOutputFileName` and `setOutputFileName` (by way of the abbreviated `outputImpl.outputFileName` syntax, as in Kotlin) from your code, hoping they will be there at runtime, even if the compile time interfaces that you know about don't have them.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explained + solutions :) @david.mihola

Comment: Note: you can call simpler applicationVariants.all{}  (without creating explicit Action object), and your ApplicationVariant will be passed as receiver parameter. Make sure not to define some lambda parameter: ".all{ variant->", otherwise it will match Kotlin's extension function. Use just plain ".all{", and you will get shorter nicer code.

Answer (score 13):

Shorter version using lambdas:

```
    applicationVariants.all{
        outputs.all {
            if(name.contains("release"))
                (this as BaseVariantOutputImpl).outputFileName = "../../apk/$name-$versionName.apk"
        }
    }
```

This will place APK into app/apk folder with name made of variant name and version code.
You can change the format of filename as you wish.
Important: it must be done only on release builds, because ".." in path corrupts debug build process with strange errors.

Comment: Just remove `..`: 
`outputFileName = "$name-$versionName.apk"` or add `./`

Answer (score 4):

For `libraryVariants` it is possible to change output file name without accessing internal api:

```
    libraryVariants.all {
        outputs.all {
            packageLibraryProvider {
                archiveFileName.set("yourlibrary-${buildType.name}.aar")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Update 04/12/23: Please proceed with caution, @Mike comment that a configuration like this might affect your project, I don't have any issues with this up to know, still renaming my APK with the configuration previously shared.

Original Answer:

For Kotlin KTS.

NOTE: This is considered a temporal solución, until a proper way to do it in KTS is released by Android team.

Working in AGP v7.1.2 it might work also in lower versions of AGP.

:app build.gradle.kts

```
android {

// ...

    this.buildOutputs.all {

        val variantOutputImpl = this as com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.BaseVariantOutputImpl

        val variantName: String = variantOutputImpl.name

        val outputFileName = "custom-name-${variantName}.apk"
        
        variantOutputImpl.outputFileName = outputFileName
    }
}
```

Comment: For latest Android Studio in November 2023, this statement destroyed the project in the IDE.   Removing the statements and resync , delete cache, etc after removing it failed.   Had to delete project and rebuild from scratch.

Comment: @Mike, sorry to read that :/, did you find a way to set a custom version name on new versions of Android Studio?