# Android gradle plugin 8.1.0 change apk name

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Old way of apk naming is no longer working, is there another api in AGP 8+?

Here's my kts build.config:

```
android {
    ...
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs
            // default type don't have outputFileName field
            .map { it as com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApkVariantOutputImpl } 
            .all { output ->
                output.outputFileName = "MyAwesomeName.apk"
                false
            }
    }
}
```

I use AGP 8.1.0 and gradle 8.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue: there are more `.all()` methods, the right one comes from `org.gradle.api.DomainObjectCollection` and not from <del>`_Collections.kt`</del>

Basically to get the right behavior we need to just remove the `it` lambda parameter.

```
// wrong
applicationVariants.all { variant -> }
// right
applicationVariants.all {  }
```

Very tricky problem

Comment: or change all to forEach

Comment: @Link182, Doesn't help for me. With Android Gradle Plugin 8.0.1 and Gradle 8.0. 
I just don't see the outputFileName property. Can you copy paste your whole block?
Any imports at the top of the file?

Comment: @Karolis this code should work https://stackoverflow.com/a/58035977/6193843

Comment: @Link182, thanks :) I ended up implementing it that way, but that cast to BaseVariantOutputImpl seems like such a hack... Really wanted to avoid using such brute methods, but there doesn't seem to be an alternative right now.

Comment: @Karolis right, I hope in the next versions of kts this api will be improved

Answer (score 3):

**Gradle:** gradle-8.0

**Gradle Type:** build.gradle.kts

You can add the setProperty inside the productFlavors.

```
android {
....

flavorDimensions += "version"
    productFlavors {
        create("free") {
            dimension = "version"

            setProperty("archivesBaseName", "free")
        }

        create("pro") {
            dimension = "version"

            setProperty("archivesBaseName", "pro2x")
        }
    }
    
}
```

it will output the pro2x-pro-debug.apk (archivesBaseName+productFlavor+buildType.apk)

Comment: You also could use setProperty() command outside of create lambda but inside productFlavors, to use something like this to setup this once
setProperty("archivesBaseName", "App-${defaultConfig.versionName}(${defaultConfig.versionCode})")

Answer (score 2):

To change an APK name in Android gradle 8.1 kts following snippet will help

```
productFlavors {
    create("free") {
        dimension = "app"
        val appName = "Free App 2.0"
        manifestPlaceholders["appName"] = appName
        applicationIdSuffix = ".demo"
        versionName = "1.0.0"
        versionNameSuffix = ".3"
        versionCode = (versionName + versionNameSuffix).replace(".", "").toInt()
        val apkName = "${appName}_$versionName$versionNameSuffix($versionCode).apk"

        // change app name block below
        buildOutputs.all {
            val variantOutputImpl = this as com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.BaseVariantOutputImpl
            variantOutputImpl.outputFileName =  apkName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@arulmani33/change-apk-name-in-android-gradle-8-1-kts-97c55fcaaa27 added in the medium thread. Feel free to add more logic there.